# Problems installing google cloud SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After I download the Google Cloud SDK install package, I trigger the install and click all the Next buttons in the wizard to accept all of the default installation options.  However, this process errors out before completion.  I've attempted this install process 3 times and it errors out each time.

Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?

[image: gcloud installation]
[image: gcloud setup error message]

Comment: Please do not include links to external sites in your question. Include the details as text in your question. Include what you specified during the wizard prompts. What is the OS version, Google Cloud SDK version? Include the relevant part from installation logfile that shows the cause of the error.

Comment: There's not enough detail in the pictures - please attach some logs.